# Where do you insert a pointer permission Json for Parse Server?

Tags: json, rest, api, parse-platform

On the parse server rest API guide is mentioned that the pointer permission is a class level permission, and there is a small sample, but is not specified where is placed:

> Pointer permissions are a special type of class-level permission that create a virtual ACL on every object in a class, based on users stored in pointer fields on those objects. For example, given a class with an owner field, setting a read pointer permission on owner will make each object in the class only readable by the user in that object’s owner field. For a class with a sender and a reciever field, a read pointer permission on the receiver field and a read and write pointer permission on the sender field will make each object in the class readable by the user in the sender and receiver field, and writable only by the user in the sender field.
>
> Pointer permissions are like virtual ACLs. They don’t appear in the ACL column, but if you are familiar with how ACLs work, you can think of them like ACLs. In the above example with the sender and receiver, each object will act as if it has an ACL of:

```
{
    "<SENDER_USER_ID>": {
        "read": true,
        "write": true
    },
    "<RECEIVER_USER_ID>": {
        "read": true
    }
}
```

> Note that this ACL is not actually created on each object. Any existing ACLs will not be modified when you add or remove pointer permissions, and any user attempting to interact with an object can only interact with the object if both the virtual ACL created by the pointer permissions, and the real ACL already on the object allow the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Pointer Permissions in the `Class Level Permissions` window opened by clicking on the `Security` tab on the class page in the Parse Dashboard. See the screenshot below:

[Parse Dashboard | Class Level permission screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSs87.png)

You can just enter the class property for which you want to add a pointer permission.